# Windows 10 cortana English (United Kingdom) fail

Tags: windows-10, cortana, language-pack, regional-settings

Is there any way to make cortana work in windows 10 on the English UK lang pack? I've set all the settings, reset all the settings, unset and reset all the settings but it just doesn't work.

I have the following installed: English (United Kingdom) LanguagePack - Windows 10 Version 1607 for AMD64-based Systems - (KB3180030) [en-GB_LP]

I've set all the region, language, keyboard, login, ui and every other possible option I can find to use English UK but to no avail.

In a weird twist of confusion, English UK is not available unless I first choose and confirm English US. I can then choose English UK but cortana is still not functional (only running in text search mode, no speech).

Any ideas?

I had a bunch of pictures showing all the settings but unfortunately I don't have the rating / xp to add images.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working now!

To fix, I needed to:

1. Select English (US)
2. Select English (UK)
3. Enable the two check boxes relating to remembering stuff about you and searching online.

After step 3, it sprang it to life.  I'll leave this here in case anyone else has a similar odd experience.

FYI, the language pack was not available until first choosing English (US) so looks like there are some bugs.